# ExtJs 6 Store not visible in Grid

Tags: extjs4.2, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm trying to port existing application from ExtJs 4.2.1 to 6.0.1
The problem that in debugger I see that grid has '**ext-empty-store**' store instead of 'store.accounting.Quota'
I can load the store directly in panel activation listener by doing 
    var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('QuotaKPI.store.accounting.Quota');
    store.load();
In firebug I see request and perfect json in response but nothing appears in the grid

Here are code snippets

app/store/accounting/Quota.js

```
Ext.define('QuotaKPI.store.accounting.Quota', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.JsonStore',
    model: 'QuotaKPI.model.accounting.QuotaModel',
    alias: 'store.accounting.Quota',
    storeId: 'QuotaKPI.store.accounting.Quota',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        ...
    }
});
```

app/view/accounting/QuotaGrid.js

```
Ext.define('QuotaKPI.view.accounting.QuotaGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel'
    ,xtype: 'QuotaGrid'
    ,store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('QuotaKPI.store.accounting.Quota')

    ,columns: [ 
    ...
    ]

    ,dockedItems : [
                   ,{xtype: 'pagingtoolbar', 
                    dock:'bottom',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('QuotaKPI.store.accounting.Quota'),
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying Quota Details {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No Quota to display"
            }
                   ]
    ,initComponent: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }       
   });
```

Store, model and grid declared in controller

```
Ext.define('QuotaKPI.controller.accounting.AccountingController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores: ['accounting.Quota'],
    models: ['accounting.QuotaModel'],
    views: ['accounting.QuotaGrid']
    ...
```

And controller itself listed in app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'QuotaKPI',
    controllers: [
        'accounting.AccountingController'
    ],
    init: function(app){
    },
    autoCreateViewport: true
});
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know *storeId* doesn't accept some character (for example "-"), I don't know for dot... in any case I suggest to make it simple.
Try "myStoreId"

In addition you can try:

```
Ext.define('QuotaKPI.view.accounting.QuotaGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel'
    ,xtype: 'QuotaGrid'
    ,store: "myStoreId",

    ,columns: [ 
    ...
    ]

    ,dockedItems : [
                   ,{xtype: 'pagingtoolbar', 
                    dock:'bottom',
            store: "myStoreId",
            displayInfo: true,
            displayMsg: 'Displaying Quota Details {0} - {1} of {2}',
            emptyMsg: "No Quota to display"
            }
                   ]
    ,initComponent: function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }       
   });
```

In addition I suggest to ensure you have a proper schema configuration (see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.schema.Schema)

And then, you could try also with ViewModel instead of *storeId* (see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html)

Don't hesitate to do a https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home

Good Luck!
Transition is not easy...

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I've change the way addressing store in grid as     //,store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('QuotaKPI.store.accounting.Quota')
    ,store: {
        type: 'accounting.Quota'
    }
and type of store to extend: 'Ext.data.Store' instead JsonStore. The grid is rendered, but show only first page.

Comment: If you do like this, even if you've set a storeId, when you create you store with *type*, you force the framework to generate a NEW instance. Try: `Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('QuotaKPI.store.accounting.Quota').getId()` and `Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup({type: 'accounting.Quota}).getId()` and you will see that the id is different. I suggest to do one way (with *storeId* or another (by ViewModel), but to be consistent within the class.   The "standard" way is the ViewModel so I suggest to really check if you need the *storeId* and else go with the ViewModel way

Comment: Thank you very much. Last comment helps me understand why I could not navigate through pages with pagination toolbar.